# Link button full height of container Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues forcing a link to take full height of its parent container.

Here is a Fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/z2ua5g4j/

```
a > span.button-single {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.box {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    height: 100%;
}

.box h1 {
    color: #667477;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.box p {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;  
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
}

.box a.button {
    width: 95px;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    margin-right:-1px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.box a.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
}
```

Basically, I want to make the gray button (on the right) take full height of the box container. As of writing, I've tried setting the link to display block and set its height to 100%, but with no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are saying `height: 100%;` But are not setting an actual height anywhere for the percentages to work.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this to understand better http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: If I set a fixed pixel height to the box container, the link still doesn't take the full height of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed box to 100px, and setup parent elements of the button to have 100% height

However, you still may want to take a look at http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm to understand how `height:100%;` is different from `width:100%;`. I'm guessing you believe they work the same.

```css
@import url("http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");

a > span.button-single {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.box {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    height: 100px;
}

.box h1 {
    color: #667477;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.box p {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;  
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
}

.box a.button {
    width: 95px;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    margin-right:-1px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.box a.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

.row{
 height: 100%;   
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum purus ut pretium ultricies. Cras pulvinar tincidunt lorem, ut posuere risus mollis in. Fusce pharetra urna nec sagittis suscipit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="height:100%;">
            <a href="#" class="button"><span class="button-single glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> More<br/>Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `btn-block` class instead of messing around with div heights, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-block" >Show Details</button></div>
```